# SQL - How to format date in column

Tags: sql, oracle

The dates provided in the Expiration Date column appear as just numbers, ie 09192019, I would like the entire column to be in a date format ie; 09/19/2019

Code:
SELECT Expiration_Date
FROM Insurance

Comment: Like: `SELECT TO_DATE(Expiration_Date, 'MMDDYYYY') FROM Insurance`?

Comment: what is EXPIRATION_DATE - a varchar2, char, clob, something character based? if so, do what @JNevill suggested. or if it's REALLY a date, rebuild the table and change the data type to DATE

Comment: Either you are using an inappropriate data type for the expiration date column, then you should change it to `DATE`. Or the tool that you are using to select data from the database is set to date format 'mmddyyyy', which you should be able to change in the program's settings.

Answer (score 2):

datatype of the table column is probably not date. I suggest you to fix the datatype by setting it to date by altering your table.

for this, use the below steps:

- `alter table Insurance add column (expiration_date_new date);`
- `update Insurance set expiration_date_new = TO_DATE(Expiration_Date, 'MM/DD/YYYY');`
- `alter table Insurance drop column expiration_Date;`
- `alter table Insurance rename column expiration_date_new to expiration_date;`

as a workarround you can convert Expiration_date column to date by

```
SELECT TO_DATE(Expiration_Date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM Insurance
```

Comment: One cannot change the data type of a column that already has data in it.